# A tool for returning an absolute static xpath pointing to a text node containing some string in xml file

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to find some record by its contents in a huge xml database. I am looking for a tool able to return a full static xpath pointing to a text node containing 'search string' in xml file.

Assume my xml file looks like:

```
<root>
  <a id="first">
    <b>Some text</b>
  </a>
  <a id="second">
    <b>The search string inside a longer text</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

If I use next xpath:

```
//text()[contains(., 'search string')]
```

it will get

```
The search string inside a longer text
```

which is correct, but not what I need. I wonder if there is a simple way to get as output or result:

```
/root/a[2]/b/
```

or

```
/root/a[@id='second']/b/
```

without coding in xslt or any xml oriented language.

Comment: Can you use lxml in python?

Comment: @JackFleeting: I can't code in lxml, but I know how to code in xslt. My question is: can you achieve the result with existing tools **without coding**.

Comment: By "without coding" you mean an xpath expression that gets the xpath of a specific element?

Comment: @JackFleeting: Yes, some xpath expression I can use as an argument of some shell command. If necessary, the output of that command can be redirected to some other shell command, but I am looking for some one liner. I found ```/usr/bin/xpath -q -e "//text()[contains(., 'search string')]/ancestor::*/name()" file.xml``` was very close to what I need, but the function ```name()``` was not accepted with this version of ```xpath```.

Comment: There's `xidel`, a shell command supporting `name()` (xpath 3.0); did you try that?

Comment: If you can use `xidel`, this command `xidel -s file.xml -e "//text()[contains(., 'search string')]/ancestor::*/(name(),count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1)"` should get you close.

Comment: @JackFleeting, checking [`path()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-path) would be more straight forward I'd say: `-e '//text()[contains(.,"search string")]/replace(path(),"Q\{\}","")'`. This returns: `/root[1]/a[2]/b[1]/text()[1]`.

Comment: @Reino: wow, if you propose your comment as a solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a tool able to return a full static xpath pointing to a text node containing 'search string' in xml file.

[Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) and the [`path()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#fn-path)-function might be what you're looking for.

```
xidel -s input.xml -e '//text()[contains(.,"search string")]/replace(path(),"Q\{\}","")'
/root[1]/a[2]/b[1]/text()[1]
```

See also [this xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22first%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cb%3ESome%20text%3C%2Fb%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20id%3D%22second%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cb%3EThe%20search%20string%20inside%20a%20longer%20text%3C%2Fb%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Ftext()%5Bcontains(.%2C%22search%20string%22)%5D%2Fpath()%2C%0A%2F%2Ftext()%5Bcontains(.%2C%22search%20string%22)%5D%2Freplace(path()%2C%22Q%5C%7B%5C%7D%22%2C%22%22)&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Answer (score 1):

Taking the comment above of Jack Fleeting into account, what about this one liner:

```
xidel -s file.xml -e "//text()[contring')]/ancestor::*/(name(),count(./preceding-sibling::*)+1)" | sed 's/^/\//;N;s/\n\([0-9]*\)/[\1]/' | tr -d '\n' ; echo
```

The last `echo` is just for cosmetics: to get the prompt of the next shell command at the beginning of the line.